# Sending a GET request using SOAP and Javascript (Google Adwords Sandbox API)

Tags: javascript, soap, google-ads-api

I'm trying to access Google Adwords Sandbox API and I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what's going on.

Here's my code:

```
        var wsUrl = "https://adwords-sandbox.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201008/CampaignService";

        var soapRequest =
                '<soapenv:Envelope \
                xmlns:soapenv="http://schemax.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" \
                xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v200906"> \
                <soapenv:Header> \
                <service>adwords</service> \
                <email>***@gmail.com</email> \
                <password>***</password> \
                <developerToken>***@gmail.com++USD</developerToken> \
                <useragent>MyApplication</useragent> \
                </soapenv:Header> \
                <soapenv:Body> \
                    <getClientAccounts/> \
                </soapenv:Body> \
                </soapenv:Envelope>';

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: wsUrl,
            contentType: document.body,
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: soapRequest,
            success: processSuccess,
            error: processError
        });

    });

    function processSuccess(data, status, req) {
        if (status == "success")
            console.log("success");
    }

    function processError(data, status, req) {
        console.log("status = " + status + " data= " + data );
    }
```

I keep getting 500 Internal Server errors. What am I doing wrong?! On the Google Adwords Sandbox website, they list simple instructions:

> To create a sandbox account, send a get request to the sandbox version
>   of CampaignService, using the WSDL location and sandbox headers as
>   described below. This initial call to the sandbox creates an MCC
>   sandbox account, along with five client accounts, for the email
>   address you specified. Your sandbox account and its client accounts
>   start out empty.
>   http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/sandbox.html

Help!

Comment: put content of header Accept as application/soap+xml??

Comment: do you mean add `<meta content-type="application/soap+xml">` to the head body? it didn't make any difference unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

AdWords API is a SOAP API, so sending the data as JSONP won't work. Also, $.ajax with cross-domain=true works only for JSON or JSONP variants, anything other than that will be stopped by the cross-domain policies of your browser.

You can try exploring the AdWords API Javascript client library instead - see http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-js/ for details.

Our primary discussion forum is at http://groups.google.com/group/adwords-api?pli=1, and I frequently answer developer questions there, so if you have any followup questions, feel free to ask there and I'll be happy to answer your questions.

Cheers,
Anash P. Oommen